# error while running django first project on my ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

```
exploit@exploit-desktop:~$ django-admin.py startproject hellodjango
bash: django-admin.py: command not found
exploit@exploit-desktop:~$ django-admin startproject mysite
bash: django-admin: command not found
exploit@exploit-desktop:~$ django-admin
bash: django-admin: command not found
exploit@exploit-desktop:~$
```

Comment: django-admin.py: command not found

Comment: Django version? Whats the output of `locate django-admin.py` ?

Comment: in console write `dj` and click `tab` two times - it shows you all commands which start with `dj`. Maybe it has different name or doesn't have `.py`

Comment: /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.pyc

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed django? Via apt

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

or pip

```
pip install django
```

If so, then go to django folder and create link to django-admin.py

```
ln -s <path>/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin
```